# Windows 11 desktop icons moving

Tags: windows-11, desktop-icons

From time to time the desktop icons are changing their position (today it happened twice  ) . Unfortunately, can't find the root cause for this.

How to solve the issue?
My mom is upset because of this.

Comment: Also align to grid and icons generally stay put. Adobe moves after updating, so you either have to manage a bit or use 3rd party software with never ending updates.

Comment: which desktop icons

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with this same issue, but only on my PC, while 5 others with the same version of Windows have not been.

The Desktop is a normal folder, just like all the others. Windows Explorer treats it as such, which means that rules for sorting and showing files are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU` and the `desktop.ini` file.

I have been able to fix the issue by erasing `desktop.ini` (to show it, disable **Hide protected operating system files** from Windows Explorer -> View -> Options -> View -> Advanced settings -> Hide protected operating system files) and by clearing `BagMRU` from the registry. Windows will re-create both as you set sorting and viewing preferences, so you do not need to worry.

Make sure you re-hide protected OS files after you are done with the process.

To test if the issue was fixed, right-click on the Desktop and apply a sort order. Right-click again and test to see if the option is checked.
If it is, the issue was fixed and your icons should no longer re-arrange themselves randomly.

Comment: I have couple of `desktop.ini` files. which one of them?

Comment: @user1977050 If you have more, there's your problem. All of them.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons (but not all) that Windows desktop icons can change
position is if :

- One changes the resolution of the desktop
- One right-clicks the desktop and chooses *Sort by*
- Some software installations will also cause the icons to regroup.

There is no solution, except to use a software that can be set to remember
the icons layout and return it if it changes.

Some such free products that I have used are :

- [ReIcon](https://www.sordum.org/8366/reicon-v2-0-restore-desktop-icon-layouts/)
- [Iconoid](https://www.sillysot.com/)
  (perhaps unsuitable for your Mom)

You will find more such products in the
[ReIcon Alternatives page](https://alternativeto.net/software/reicon/).

Answer (score 0):

Broken windows is broken, you can't fix it. The only solution I found for this issue is to use a third party software. It's open source, it's free, no installation, no registry entries, and it doesn't call home.

ICU - Icon Configuration Utility: https://funk.eu/icu-icon-configuration-utility/

It's stores the resolution and the location of each file on your desktop in a single file. Double click it and your icons will be rearranged as you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

The following solved the problem in my case:

1st  Right-click the empty space on the desktop, then select View and uncheck Auto arrange icons.

2nd  Rename those icons that tend to move. (In most cases you can choose as their new name their earlier name (i.e. the same name)).

Answer (score -1):

I didnt track "why", but they are not actually moved anywhere, they, go to "default" setting, for me, on 3 different machines(all Win11), i "restore" them by holding Ctrl and quickly scroll mouse up and down(or down and up). For each, screen/res/iconpos(size/etc)/etc win11 holds Bags :D you just have to "refresh" it to your own. Btw, speed of scrolling has nothing to it, its just change icon size command. *Edit:This happens totally on random, computer doesn't have to work anything just by having desktop loaded, it can happen.